# Display ANSI colours in text file in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, ansi-escape

I have a `.txt` file with some escape codes to show colour like this:

```
[0m[32mWord[0m
```

Is there a way I can view these files with colour in PyCharm? I tried the [ANSI Highlighter Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9707-ansi-highlighter) but it seems to be defunct.

Just converting to a *.log or *.md file didn't help either.

Comment: Just use the terminal. Not a great solution, but CSI sequences are supposed to be used only on terminals. Files should never include them (and nobody should emit CSI sequences hardcoded: we have various terminal libraries which handles different terminals [and so also plain files]). Python as `blessing` which call curses (and so its huge terminal database).

Answer (score 3):

The [ANSI Highlighter Premium](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9707-ansi-highlighter-premium/) plugin works (but it is not free). You may need to enable it for the file types you want to display with ANSI colours.

I didn't bother to change the configuration for `.txt` files, so I copied a `.txt` file containing ANSI colour codes to a file with the extension `.log`. Then PyCharm notified me that the file type was recognised by the plugin and asked whether I wanted to enable it. After enabling, colours are displayed just fine.